# Best Method Cancan With Many Roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

Looking for some general advice and tips about using cancan on our latest rails3 project.

We're building an ordering system which we use internally and provide restricted client access. These include:

> ```
> Superadmin
> Superaccounts
> Supertechs 
> Clientadmin
> Clientaccounts
> Clienttechs
> ```

In our views, we've previously used a combination of:

> <% if can? :manage User %>

And

> <% if current_user.role_ids.include?(2) %>

I suspect the latter is bad practice and would appreciate finding out how to best achieve the same method.

We're also a little confused about how to deal with many roles.

What's the best way to provide access to multiple user groups - i.e. superadmin and supertechs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option to replace

```
<% if current_user.role_ids.include?(2) %>
```

is to create a method for each role inside the model, for example:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  .
  . 
  def super_admin?
    self.role_ids.include?(2)
  end
  .
  .
```

This way you will remove the query logic from the views and keep it on the controller and you will also be able access the roles by simply doing:

```
<% if current_user.super_admin? %>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Amazingly, I just spotted this having been awarded the tumbleweed award. I didn't know you could do this! Is there a way to include multiple roles, or inherit upwards? Jx